# Gray color turns brown in ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, color

Why does this code not create a gray plane, as it should? It seems like there is a hint of orange in there, creating an overal "brownish" surface.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Specularity[White, 10], Opacity[1]] ]
```

Comment: Add `Lighting -> "Neutral"`.

Comment: From the docs, "Lighting->Automatic uses ambient light together with four light sources fixed relative to the final displayed image. With the typical default setting ColorFunction->Automatic, colored light sources are used; if an explicit setting for ColorFunction is given, the light sources are taken to be white."

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the default lighting was "colorful." Adding `Lighting -> "Neutral"` works perfectly.